# Как приостановить выполнения скрипта до пользовательских действий?

Tags: javascript

Есть следующая проблема. Во время ajax-запроса формируется модальное окно. Я заменяю все alert() и confirm() на модальные окна. Необходимо приостановить выполнение скрипта до пользовательских действий. Грубо говоря, если пользователь нажмет кнопку "ok" скрипт продолжиться выполняться дальше, а если нажмет кнопку отмены, то скрипт будет отрабатывать по другому варианту. Нужно именно функционал как при alert() приостановить скрипт пока пользователь не нажмет кнопку

Comment: Можно же повесить на "ok" вторую половину скрипта и все. То есть, пока пользователь не запустит это событие - ничего выполняться не будет.

Comment: Как при алерте сделать не получится. Браузер не может одновременно остановить работу синхронного скрипта и не останавливать для кнопки. Для этого нужен асинхронный подход с событием клика, как описал комментатор выше.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что я не знаю, что может быть после скрипта: редирект, какой-то другой скрипт или прекращение скрипта.